How can I send instance attributes from Geometry Nodes to Shading Editor?
I have a file created with Blender 4.1. My GeoNode creates instances and changes their color based on their ID using "Store Named Attribute" and creating an attribute named "color", different on each instance.
Down the line, there is a "Realize Instances", if that helps.
In the Shader Editor, I recover that value with "Attribute".


Everything works well with Blender 4.1, but when I open that file with Blender 4.2, all my instances are red (ID=0).
I guess there has been some change, but where? How should I proceed to update my file in order to obtain the same result?

Set the Attribute > Type to Instancer when you want to access data from instances. However, you say there is a Realize Instances node "down the line" and you do not show your complete nodetree, so I cannot verify that this is the full solution to your issue.


I'm sorry I don't show my whole tree, but it's huge! Nonetheless, I found the answer: "Relalize Instances has a new "Realize All" tick that I should untick. I'll edit my question, adding that part. Feel free to edit your answer afterwards.

@SteeveDroz How should I edit my answer? The question seemed as if you stored data on instances, therefore you have to use Instancer on the Attribute node. Now I only know you realize some instances but not all, but there is still no information on which part your data is now stored...

Just add "also uncheck Realize All in Realize Instances" and your answer solves my problem ;-), I will accept it as the Chosen One. (sorry, I'm a bit sick and I'm not sure I'm clear)

If I would say that just from the question it would only be wild speculation. I would actually rather say, since you store the data on instances, do not use a Realize Instances at all.
